# Error code 38189, 'title': 'Internal error', 'detail': 'An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator status 500

Tags: amadeus

I always get

```
{'errors': [{'code': 38189, 'title': 'Internal error', 'detail': 'An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator', 'status': 500}]}
```

when calling POST on flight offers pricing API, flight offer API works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Content-Type is "application/json" and not "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

If you are using Python requests, make sure that you are using:

requests.post(..., **json**=payload, ...)

and not:

requests.post(..., **data**=payload, ...)